# Selenium works on eclipse, times out on jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, css-selectors, jenkins-plugins

Our UAT is a little slow so when I run my selenium test it works on eclipse however it times out on jenkins. When you watch the test run on eclipse you can see that where it fails to locate the css selector on jenkins its actually just having a long pause however jenkins just does a timeout error and doesn't wait.

Is there a way to extended how long jenkins waits before a timeout.

(the timeout error failing to locate css selector which works fine on local machine)

org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.cssSelector: #q_386115 (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Answer (score 0):

Use Wait wait= new FluentWait<>(driver) with timeout setting  and then user wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElemenentLocated(By.xpath(""))) and then take action on element.